# Question on D'Alembert's formula

Tags: waves, boundary-conditions

On page 3 of [these lecture notes](http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/teaching/m435s14/PDE-Notes2013.pdf), it says:

> $$u(x,t)= \frac 1{2c}[ f(x+t)+ f(x-t) ]+ \frac1{2c} \int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} g(y)dy .$$
>   This important expression is known as D'Alembert's formula.  Letting $G$ denote the antiderivative of $g$ vanishing at $x=0$, we may write this as:
>   $$u(x,t)=\frac12[(f+\frac1cG(x+ct)+(f-\frac1cG(x-ct))], G'=g, G(0)=0 . $$

My question is why is it required that $G(0)=0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like this is necessary, maybe they just require that to be definite.

Comment: Thanks--but what does definite mean here?

Comment: @user45664: It means that they probably wanted  to make their prescription better defined.